# Delete multiple records using REST Api

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest

I am trying to delete multiple records using REST Api.

using below url **https://xxx.salesforce.com/v43.0/composite/sobjects?ids=00P0K000016YabaUAG,00P0K000016YabaUAG**

but in response I am getting **405 Http method DELETE is not supported by this URL**

What is wrong with the above URL or is there any other way to delete multiple records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think endpoint URL should be:

https://ap6.salesforce.com/**services**/data/v43.0/composite/sobjects?ids=00P0K000016YWusUAG,00P0K000016YWutUAG